# Wait when equivalent request is pending

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, queue

I have this code:

```
var data = {};
var dataPending = {};
function getData(name, callback) {
    callback = callback || function() {};
    // new response
    if (!data[name] && !dataPending[name]) {
        dataPending[name] = true;
        sendGetRequest({
            url      : '/blah-blah/' + name,
            callback : function(response) {
                data[name] = response;
                delete dataPending[name];
                return callback();
            }
        });
    // equivalent request in progress
    } else if (dataPending[name]) {
        // TODO how to wait for equivalent request is completed and return callback?
    // data is exists
    } else {
        return callback();
    }
}
getData('name1', function() { ... });
getData('name1', function() { ... });
getData('name2', function() { ... });
getData('name2', function() { ... });
getData('name1', function() { ... });
```

Function sendGetRequest is wrapper of xmlhttprequest. It works. But...
How to wait for equivalent request is completed and return callback?

Comment: I think you may be looking for promises: http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: @Gerard Downes without jquery

Comment: maybe use https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: @Evan like this: http://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/1/61/896/61896021_PA271852.JPG

Comment: more like: http://i.imgur.com/1FDxak5.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an array variable that you can push requests to to wait. Then in your original callback, if there's an item in the array, grab the first one, remove it from the array, and call getData.

e.g.,

```
var dataQueue = [];
var active = false;
function getData(name, callback, force) {
    if(active && !!force) {
        dataQueue.push({name: name, callback: callback});
    }
    else {
        active = true;
        sendGetRequest({
            url: '/blah-blah/' + name,
            callback : function(response) {
                if(dataQueue.length > 0) {
                    active = false;
                }
                else {
                    var reqObj = dataQueue.shift();
                    getData(reqObj.name, reqObj.callback, true);
                }
                return callback();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to have a flag indicating whether work is being done or not and an array to hold onto requests we want to wait to send. When you do get data, if we're already processing a request (via our `active` flag) push the item into the queue, otherwise go ahead and run it and set active to true. On the callback for `sendGetRequest` we see if the `dataQueue` has any items - if it doesn't, we're no longer active so set the flag to false. If there are items, get the first item of the array and remove it. Then call getData on that item, setting force to true, to allow it to process.

Do note that the logic to check to see if the queue has items in it inside the callback should be broken out into a seperate function. You may also want to wrap it in a `setTimeout` with 0MS so `return callback()` doesn't have to wait for the queue handling logic.

Comment: yes, but always required return callback result. Possible wait inside one getData scope instance?

Comment: @Deep Sorry I guess I'm a little confused - the `sendGetRequest` callback is doing `return callback();` every time it's called. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: oops.. )) Yes, this is my fail. Yes, this must wait and for callback of sendGetRequest. Ok, here is stupid logic. Need rewrite this code. Thanks for help!